# Do I need user permission to know their location using their IP?

Tags: web-applications, ip, geoip2

I need to use user's IP address to get their approximate location like country, state and if possibly city. Do laws require me to get user's permission to use their IP address to find their location via geoip2 ? 
I am not planning to use location information for targeted advertisement. It will just better serve user to use web application. Are these laws same in USA, Europe and Russia?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about legal issues and not directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever your website or application collects data from your users, it’s typically a legal requirement to write a [privacy policy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_policy).

As long as you mention the data you’re collecting in there, you should be okay, just as long as you’re using lawful means to collect. For example:

- We will talk to your Mum and ask her about your hobbies and likes to create a model of your interests: totally okay.
- We will hack your Facebook in order to find sensitive information in your messages and extort you: probably not okay.

As a rule of thumb, if there’s data to collect, Google’s already collecting it. If it’s in their privacy policy, you’re probably fine to do the same thing.

> When you use Google services, we may collect and process information about your actual location. We use various technologies to determine location, including IP address, GPS and other sensors that may, for example, provide Google with information on nearby devices, Wi-Fi access points and mobile towers.